How to make sure Kerberos cifs service ticket is valid long enough for copy operation
I have a backup job that copies large files to a kerberos secured cifs share on a Windows Server. Sometimes the job hangs indefinitely, and there is a kernel cifs process spinning at 100% cpu.
I believe this happens when the kerberos service ticket's lifetime for the cifs service expires during the copy operation. If I trigger a file operation in another shell instance on the cifs share under the service account, the original job actually continues its operation.
So, I am looking for a way to ensure that the kerberos service ticket in the ticket cache is valid for more than one hour. Even better would be if there is a setting that the cifs module would automatically renew the service ticket during operation.
A catch here is that the job itself is not aware of the share name it copies to (obviously its just a target path to it, mounted via autofs). Also, the share could also be in use somewhere else (other job). So simply deleting the current service ticket prior to getting a new one might make other jobs fail.
If no intelligent auto renewal is possible, maybe a solution could be automatically renewing all service tickets available in the ticket cache. A valid krbtgt ticket is always  available, as there is a k5start job running for that. Is there a way to do that?
System: Ubuntu server 22.04. (kernel 5.15.0-122).
SSSD is configured to automatically log user on to kerberos server. Automatic ticket retrieval is working on access to a autofs multiuser cifs share.

Honestly, I'd start with a bug report to the kernel cifs team...
